# How to pull out alpha and count digits using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to build Regex in C#. I need to know how to pull out alpha and count digits using Regex.

```
string example = "ASDFG 3457";
```

Need to pull out of "ASDFG" and then count digits (eg 4 or 5 - 7). If finding 4 digits, return value = 3457 without alpha. How to do this in C#?
I know it is better to do without regex but i have a requirement that i must use regex for a reason.

Comment: No need for regex at all.

Comment: it is very new to me. not sure how to do this. if you give me your example code so that i would get a picture in my mind and i will write on my own further... thanks

Comment: You "reason" looks like homework. You ought to inform us if such is the case. Given this, i tried to give my answer as a guideline/jump start and not lead you directly to a solution

Answer (score 2):

If all your doing is trying to get the numbers from a piece of text you can do this:

```
         string expr=@"\d+";
         string text="ASDFG 3457":         
         MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, expr);
         foreach (Match m in mc)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
         }
```

Comment: But there are other perhaps easier ways to do this without regex.

Comment: i know it is better to do without regex but i have a requirement that i must use regex for a reason. after pulling out text, how to count digits?

Comment: The foreach will display all the digits it pulls out, the MatchCollection may have something similar to .count or .length have a look, but if not you can just initialise an int before the foreach and add one to it every time it loops round.

Answer (score 1):

regex

```
(?<alpha>\w*) (?<number>\d*)
```

this extracts two named groups: alpha and number.
It assumes the first group only contain words and the second only contains digits and that they are separated by a blank space. 
None of them are mandatory.

If you need to make them mandatory you could replace `*` with `+`
You can also force the number of digits to four with `\d{4}`

I'd recommend you reading a regex tutorial and take some c# sample from the web. @Srb1313711 answer already helps you on that.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously (cough) the simplest "solution" is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    private static IEnumerable<long> ParseNumbers(IEnumerable<char> stream)
    {
        bool eos = false;

        using (var it = stream.GetEnumerator())
            do
            {
                Func<bool> advance = () => !(eos = !it.MoveNext());

                while (advance() && !char.IsDigit(it.Current)) ;

                if (eos) break;

                long accum = 0;
                do accum = accum * 10 + (it.Current - '0');
                while (advance() && char.IsDigit(it.Current));

                yield return accum;
            }
            while (!eos);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var num in ParseNumbers("ASDFG 3457 ASDFG.\n 123457"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num);
        }
    }
}
```

For fun, of course.

### Edit

For more fun: the `unsafe` variation. Note this is also no longer deferred, so it won't work if not all input has arrived yet, and it generates an *eager* list of values:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    private static unsafe List<long> ParseNumbers(char[] input)
    {
        var r = new List<long>();

        fixed (char* begin = input)
        {
            char* it = begin, end = begin + input.Length;

            while (true)
            {
                while (it != end && (*it < '0' || *it > '9')) 
                    ++it;

                if (it == end) break;

                long accum = 0;
                while (it != end && *it >= '0' && *it <= '9') 
                    accum = accum * 10 + (*(it++) - '0');

                r.Add(accum);
            }
        }

        return r;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var number in ParseNumbers("ASDFG 3457 ASDFG.\n 123457".ToCharArray()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This regular expression will:

- capture the text into group 1
- count the number of digits and place them into a capture group based on how many where found

  - Capture group 2 will have numbers which are 8 or more digits long
  - Capture group 3 will have numbers which are 5-7 digits long
  - Capture group 4 will have numbers which are exactly 4 digits long
  - Capture group 5 will have numbers which are 1-3 digits long

`([A-Za-z]*) (?:(\d{8,})|(\d{5,7})|(\d{4})|(\d{1,3}))`

[image]

## Example

Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/AIO9uUNNQc

**Sample Text**

```
ASDFG 1234567890
ASDFG 123456789
ASDFG 12345678
ASDFG 1234567
ASDFG 123456
ASDFG 12345
ASDFG 1234
ASDFG 123
ASDFG 12
ASDFG 1
```

**Capture Groups**

```
[0][0] = ASDFG 1234567890
[0][1] = ASDFG
[0][2] = 1234567890
[0][3] = 
[0][4] = 
[0][5] = 

[1][0] = ASDFG 123456789
[1][1] = ASDFG
[1][2] = 123456789
[1][3] = 
[1][4] = 
[1][5] = 

[2][0] = ASDFG 12345678
[2][1] = ASDFG
[2][2] = 12345678
[2][3] = 
[2][4] = 
[2][5] = 

[3][0] = ASDFG 1234567
[3][1] = ASDFG
[3][2] = 
[3][3] = 1234567
[3][4] = 
[3][5] = 
[4][0] = ASDFG 123456
[4][1] = ASDFG
[4][2] = 
[4][3] = 123456
[4][4] = 
[4][5] = 

[5][0] = ASDFG 12345
[5][1] = ASDFG
[5][2] = 
[5][3] = 12345
[5][4] = 
[5][5] = 

[6][0] = ASDFG 1234
[6][1] = ASDFG
[6][2] = 
[6][3] = 
[6][4] = 1234
[6][5] = 

[7][0] = ASDFG 123
[7][1] = ASDFG
[7][2] = 
[7][3] = 
[7][4] = 
[7][5] = 123
[8][0] = ASDFG 12
[8][1] = ASDFG
[8][2] = 
[8][3] = 
[8][4] = 
[8][5] = 12

[9][0] = ASDFG 1
[9][1] = ASDFG
[9][2] = 
[9][3] = 
[9][4] = 
[9][5] = 1
```