# In C# datatype* means

Tags: c#, types

what exactly this means

Datatype*

**Example** : int*,  double*,   char*,...

Can any one give some explanation for it please.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That's C / C++, not C#. It's a pointer: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node10.html

Comment: Here are the datatypes in c#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush blinders off :)

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush [C# has pointers too.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Ah, forgot about the unsafe keyword..

Comment: Shame on those who approved the edit that changed part of this question to C++ (perhaps appropriately, perhaps inappropriately) while keeping references to C# too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an unsafe pointer. **[Unsafe Code Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474(v=vs.71).aspx)**

Here is an examples using it: [How to pull out alpha and count digits using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807277/how-to-pull-out-alpha-and-count-digits-using-regex/17807910#17807910)

```
private static unsafe List<long> ParseNumbers(char[] input)
{
    var r = new List<long>();

    fixed (char* begin = input)
    {
        char* it = begin, end = begin + input.Length;

        while (true)
        {
            while (it != end && (*it < '0' || *it > '9')) 
                ++it;

            if (it == end) break;

            long accum = 0;
            while (it != end && *it >= '0' && *it <= '9') 
                accum = accum * 10 + (*(it++) - '0');

            r.Add(accum);
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Pointer types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> In an unsafe context, a type may be a pointer type, a value type, or a
>   reference type. A pointer type declaration takes one of the following
>   forms:
>
> type* identifier;
>
> void* identifier; //allowed but not recommended

Answer (score 1):

Those are [Pointer types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> In an unsafe context, a type may be a pointer type as well as a value type or a reference type. A pointer type declaration takes one of the following forms:

```
 type* identifier;
 void* identifier; //allowed but not recommended
```

Answer (score 1):

They are called [`Pointer types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/y31yhkeb.aspx)

> In an unsafe context, a type may be a pointer-type as well as a
>   value-type or a reference-type. However, a pointer-type may also be
>   used in a typeof expression outside of an unsafe context
>   as such usage is not unsafe.
>
> A pointer-type is written as an unmanaged-type or the keyword void,
>   followed by a * token:
>
> The type specified before the * in a pointer type is called the
>   referent type of the pointer type. It represents the type of the
>   variable to which a value of the pointer type points.
>
> Unlike references (values of reference types), pointers are not
>   tracked by the garbage collector—the garbage collector has no
>   knowledge of pointers and the data to which they point. For this
>   reason a pointer is not permitted to point to a reference or to a
>   struct that contains references, and the referent type of a pointer
>   must be an unmanaged-type.

Answer (score 1):

This is pointer in c#

please take a time to read this [Unsafe Code Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
using System;

class Test
{
    // The unsafe keyword allows pointers to be used within
    // the following method:
    static unsafe void Copy(byte[] src, int srcIndex,
        byte[] dst, int dstIndex, int count)
    {
        if (src == null || srcIndex < 0 ||
            dst == null || dstIndex < 0 || count < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        int srcLen = src.Length;
        int dstLen = dst.Length;
        if (srcLen - srcIndex < count ||
            dstLen - dstIndex < count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }


            // The following fixed statement pins the location of
            // the src and dst objects in memory so that they will
            // not be moved by garbage collection.          
            fixed (byte* pSrc = src, pDst = dst)
            {
                  byte* ps = pSrc;
                  byte* pd = pDst;

            // Loop over the count in blocks of 4 bytes, copying an
            // integer (4 bytes) at a time:
            for (int n =0 ; n < count/4 ; n++)
            {
                *((int*)pd) = *((int*)ps);
                pd += 4;
                ps += 4;
            }

            // Complete the copy by moving any bytes that weren't
            // moved in blocks of 4:
            for (int n =0; n < count%4; n++)
            {
                *pd = *ps;
                pd++;
                ps++;
            }
            }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        byte[] a = new byte[100];
        byte[] b = new byte[100];
        for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) 
           a[i] = (byte)i;
        Copy(a, 0, b, 0, 100);
        Console.WriteLine("The first 10 elements are:");
        for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) 
           Console.Write(b[i] + " ");
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

and output

```
The first 10 elements are:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

i tooth this will give you an idea to understated pointer in c# and also how to use it

best of luck